# Radiobutton changes state in another child when radiobutton is clicked

Tags: javascript, android

I have a really wierd problem with my ExpandableListview with listview and radiobuttons inside.

**Problem:** When I click on a radiobutton in the first child inside the first expandablelistview, the radiobutton in third child(row) in the second expandablelistview also changes state. It seems like its also "un-activating" radiobuttons when some are clicked.

If anyone know what might cause this behavior I would very much appreciate some feedback. I've used RadioGroups by the way.

*Awesome drawn picture to illustrate the problem*[image: Image showing problem]:

*mek_list_layout XML with ExpandableListView:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

*list_group XML for the list group*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#C0C0C0">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*list_item XML for the textview, radioGroup and two radio buttons*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/question"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:layout_width="250dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnPositive"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="JA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnNegative"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="NEJ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*My ExpandableListAdapter*

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> listDataChild;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return listDataChild.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
}  

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;

    if( convertView != null )
        view = convertView;

    else    
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false); 
    Question question = (Question)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
   TextView txtviewquestion = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.question );

if( txtviewquestion != null )
    txtviewquestion.setText(question.getQuestion());

//***TITTA NÄRMARE PÅ KNAPPARNA******
//Button btnPositive = (Button)view.findViewById( R.id.BtnPositive );
//btnPositive.setChecked( c.getState() );
//Button btnNegative = (Button)view.findViewById( R.id.BtnNegative );
//btnNegative.setChecked( c.getState() );
return view;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return listDataChild.get( groupPosition ).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,   ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;
//String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (convertView != null) {
    view = convertView;
} else
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
String getgroup = (String)getGroup (groupPosition);
TextView questiongroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

if ( getgroup != null) 
    questiongroup.setText (getgroup);




/** 
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
}

TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

return convertView;
**/
return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}

public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {}

public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}
}
```

*QuestionActivtyMek - My Activity class*

```
public class QuestionActivityMek extends ExpandableListActivity {


private static final String LOG_TAG = "QuestionActivity2";
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
//HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mek_list_layout);

    ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupNames.add("1. TÄNK IGENOM UPPDRAGET");
    groupNames.add("2. IDENTIFIERA FAROR I UPPDRAGET");

    //*****SE ÖVER OM ARRAYEN SKA VARA AV QUESTION OBJEKT*****
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> questions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>>();
    ArrayList<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig vad uppdraget innebär?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig hur jag tar mig till arbetsplatsen säkert?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig vilka arbetsmoment som ingår i uppdraget?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig vad som behöver brytas och låsas avs el, hydraulik, pneumatik och vatten?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag kommunicerat med kontaktman samt berörda operatörer och ledningen?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag tillgång till instruktioner och tagit del av de lokala skyddsföreskrifterna?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag nödvändiga verktyg och tillstånd för uppdraget?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag rätt personlig skyddsutrustning för uppdraget?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Behövs avspärring av det aktuella området?", true));
    questions.add(question);
    question = new ArrayList<Question>();
    question.add(new Question("Riskerar jag att snubbla/halka/falla? Check underlag,skyddsräcken, trappor, trappsteg och arbetsplatformar", true));
    question.add (new Question("Påkörningsrisk, travers eller truck?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag kontrollerat att all strömförsörjning är bruten och låst?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag förvissat mig om att all hydraulik, pneumatik eller vattentryck är avlastade samt reglagen brutna och låsta?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Ensamarbete i så fall hur kommunicera?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Höghöjdsarbete?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Förekommer kemikalier/farliga ämnen och föreligger brandrisk?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Riskerar jag att påverkas av gas, ångor eller damm?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Riskerar jag att tappa eller få fallande föremål på mig?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Riskerar jag att bli fastklämd?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Riskerar jag att utsättas för buller och vibrationer?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Finns risk för elgenomströmning/-ljusbåge?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Förekommer tunga manuella lyft under uppdraget?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Finns risk för brännskada?", true));
    question.add (new Question("Riskerar jag att utsättas för stressmoment under arbetets gång?", true));
    questions.add(question);
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter (this, groupNames, questions);
    setListAdapter (listAdapter);
}

public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onContentChanged");
}
```